# How to execute app.component constructor code first

Tags: angular

I've a Boolean function in app.component constructor that helps switch between two sidebars but it only works after a reload. How to make it execute without an reload.

Comment: Share code and stackbiltz

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding 
you need to call that boolean function form View i.e Html file 
when you reload the page, the component initializes and calls the constructor implicitly

so you need to find any click or toggle event from HTML view to call your toggle function to toggle the side bar.

Thanks